# How to join to find these results?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

Table AA

```
table AA
ID  Date 
1   2018.01.21
2   2018.01.22
2   2018.05.27
2   2018.07.15


table BB
ID  Date 
1   2017.05.21
1   2017.08.27
1   2018.01.23
1   2018.02.15
2   2017.01.01
2   2017.05.31
2   2018.01.01
2   2018.01.25
2   2018.05.29
2   2018.09.30
```

I want to join these table on ID column. And the purpose is to find dates in table B that are the same as or later than the min date in table A, per id and date (on table A per row).

I mean the output should be

```
OUTPUT

1   2018.01.23
2   2018.01.25
2   2018.05.29
2   2018.09.30
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You say `And the purpose is find the min date on table B which is bigger equal (>=) than table A.`, but your output almost reads like `the purpose is to find dates in table B that are the same as or later than the min date in table A, per id`. Which is correct? Either your output should have one row per id, or there should be multiple rows for each (since for id = 1, there are two rows in table B which are greater than either row in table A, but your output only shows one row. However, there are multiple rws for id = 2 in the output.)

Comment: Shouldn't the row with `2018.02.15` for id = 1 be included in the output? If not, why not? It's greater than `2018.01.21`.

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: for ID=1 the min output for (id =1 and date = 2018.01.21) is 2018.01.23 on table B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this.

you only need to write a subquery in `select` and get `MIN` date from `BB` table.

```
CREATE TABLE AA(
  ID INT,
  "DATE" DATE
);
INSERT INTO AA VALUES(1,to_date('2018-01-21','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO AA VALUES(2,to_date('2018-01-22','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO AA VALUES(2,to_date('2018-05-27','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO AA VALUES(2,to_date('2018-07-15','yyyy-MM-dd'));



CREATE TABLE BB(
  ID INT,
  "DATE" DATE
);

INSERT INTO BB VALUES(1,to_date('2017-05-21','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(1,to_date('2017-08-27','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(1,to_date('2018-01-23','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(1,to_date('2018-02-15','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(2,to_date('2017-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(2,to_date('2017-05-31','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(2,to_date('2018-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(2,to_date('2018-01-25','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(2,to_date('2018-05-29','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(2,to_date('2018-07-31','yyyy-MM-dd'));
INSERT INTO BB VALUES(2,to_date('2018-09-30','yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT a1.Id,(
  SELECT MIN(b1."DATE")
  FROM BB b1
  where a1.ID = b1.ID and b1."DATE" >= a1."DATE"
) "Date"
FROM AA a1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d07e/1/0)**:

```
| ID |                 Date |
|----|----------------------|
|  1 | 2018-01-23T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2018-01-25T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2018-05-29T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2018-07-31T00:00:00Z |
```